# How to rewrite this code snippet using Sandi Metz rules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, class-design

Supposing I have a `Survey` rails model that `has_many: questions` and a need to be able to resequence the questions...

Where would I put the `renumber_questions` method (Survey model, Question model, or other class, and why?) and how would this ugly method below best be written following the [rules](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers)?

```
  def renumber_questions
    last_page = 0
    new_page = 0
    new_seq = 0
    questions.unscope(:order).order(page: :asc, seq: :asc).each do |question|
      if last_page != question.page
        new_page = new_page + 1
      end
      last_page = question.page

      new_seq = new_seq + 1
      question.page = new_page
      question.seq = new_seq
      question.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it on another class, because of Single Responsibility (mentioned in the link you gave).

> Despite the large number of private methods we wrote, keeping classes short proved easy. It forced us to consider what the single responsibility of our class was, and what should be extracted.

```
class RenumberQuestions
  def initialize(questions)
    @questions = questions.unscope(:order).order(page: :asc, seq: :asc)
    @last_page = 0
    @new_page = 0
    @new_seq = 0
  end

  def call
    @questions.each do |question|
      counting_var(question)
      mutate_(question)
    end
  end

  def counting_var(question)
    @new_page += 1 if @last_page != question.page
    @last_page = question.page
    @new_seq += 1
  end

  def mutate_(question)
    question.page = @new_page
    question.seq = @new_seq
    question.save
  end
end
```

Sorry for the bad naming. I don't know what you do, so I just naming it as I understand. And you can make this more clean.